# startup disk creator error "unable to mount blank DVD-R Disc location is already mounted"

Tags: 12.10, startup, dvd, burning

My os is ubuntu 12.10 32 bit desktop. (Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU E6500 @ 2.93GHz × 2) .
When trying to burn the lubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.iso file on a blank DVD-R Disc, using the startup disk creator, I get this error: unable to mount blank DVD-R Disc location is already mounted. I have never encountered such problem before. 
What is wrong and how to correct it?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-settings-daemon/+bug/1069964). But there is a workaround.

When the autorun window comes up with the error 'unable to mount blank DVD-R Disc location is already mounted' just ignore/cancel the error and choose Brasero in 'Ask what to do?' dialogue.

[image]

Then in Brasero;

- `Project` > `Open`
- Open the image to burn.
- `Burn`. DVD-R would then burn fine.

Answer (score 0):

Startup Disk Creator is not for burning CD or DVD images. Startup Disk Creator is for making a bootable live/install system on USB flash or drive (USB memory stick, SD in USB card reader, etc.).

Use Brasero or Xfburn or any other program you use for burning to burn the iso on a dvd.

Comment: Thanks. I used Brasero successfully,though I got the same error.  I tried K3b and got the same error, so it seems to me that the problem does not derive from the burners.

Comment: This seems to be a confirmed bug in ubuntu 12.10: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1071739 .